# What physical layout for Unit-Tested projects?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, structure, boost-test

At the moment, I'm learning about Unit-Testing and I want to integrate testing to my current (10 files of OpenGL experiments) project. For this purpose I downloaded Boost.Test, and while I can figure out how it works on a single file sample, I have no idea about how to integrate it in my project (I'd like to use static link version).

Are test a different binary from the application itself ? (if it's one binary, how to run it ?) Should I create a test file for every tested class ? How much should my CMakeLists change to reflect this integration ? Is it possible to decouple testing from the application, in a way that I can build my app on a platform where I didn't install boost ?

I know I have many questions, but to put it simply : how is Boost.Test used in real life ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weather your project builds a library or executable, I suggest you create an extra test runner executable. In my projects I normally have the following layout:

```
/mylib
  CMakeLists.txt
  /inc
    ClassA.hpp
    ClassB.hpp
  /src
    ClassA.cpp
    ClassB.cpp
  /test
    ClassA_test.cpp
    ClassB_test.cpp
    main_test.cpp
```

As you see there is a test file for every class. This has the main benefit of reducing compilation dependencies. In my `CMakeLists.txt` I then create my library and the associated test runner

```
# Get Boost
find_package ( Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework )
# Here you set library sources, use file ( GLOB ... ) if you have many
set ( SOURCES ClassA.cpp ClassB.cpp )    
add_library ( mylib ${SOURCES} )

if (Boost_FOUND)
  # Here you set test sources, use file ( GLOB ... ) if you have many
  set ( TESTSOURCES ClassA_test.cpp ClassB_test.cpp )    
  # This creates the test runner
  add_executable (  mylib_test_runner ${TESTSOURCES} )
  # Here the tests of the runner are linked to the related library and Boost
  target_link_libraries ( mylib_test_runner mylib ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY} )
endif ( )
```

The file main_test.cpp is only there to automatically generate the main function for the test runner

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTestSuite
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

Then, for example, `ClassB_test.cpp` might have the following layout:

```
#include "../inc/ClassB.hpp"
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE ( ClassBTest )

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE ( TestFoo )
{
  BOOST_CHECK(true);
}

...

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END() // ClassBTest
```

So wrapping up:

- Are test a different binary from the application itself? - Yes, that
  is possible and certainly helpful.
- If it's one binary, how to run it? - In this case: `./mylib_test_runner`
- Should I create a test file for every tested class? - I suggest you do.
- How much should my CMakeLists change to reflect this integration? - See the example.
- Is it possible to decouple testing from the application, in a way that I
  can build my app on a platform where I didn't install boost? - The
  check for Boost_FOUND takes care of this, you could also add an
  option to your CMakeLists.txt and check against that. I personally think this is even better.

Comment: Shouldn't I also add "src" and "inc" files to mylib_test_runner ?

Comment: @bisthebis Your test files will of course include the class headers. But symbol resolution will be handled by the linker.